# How can I make a field in a MongoDB document change after a set amount of time?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am building an application using JS / Node.JS / Express / MongoDB. Users can purchase a listing. The listing gets stored as a document in a MongoDB database. I would like for the listing to "expire" after a set amount of time (for example, 30 days). I'm thinking just a boolean field in the document called "expired" that defaults to false, but switches to true after the time runs out. Is there a way to use JavaScript to attach a timer to each listing, and then trigger the change in the DB after the expiration of the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a TTL index for the same. TTL (Time to live)  index deletes the document after a given time.

You can create TTL index as below :

```
product.createIndexes({ "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
```

here product is the schema. You should change lastModifiedDate to the field on which you are deciding to remove the document after a certain time.

You can create an index either using the driver in nodejs or on the collection itself in mongo shell.

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing I will need to keep 2 separate schemas if I want to give the user the ability to restore an expired document?